# sslh --transparent not working: nginx not answering SYN

Tags: linux, networking, proxy

I am trying to set up sslh with the `--transparent` option. It is not working.

I am running my real nginx instance on port 1443. When I run tcpdump, I see that `sslh` successfully masquaraded as the real originator, but for some reason when the SYN packet arrives with the false source, no reply is sent to *any* of the interfaces. The SYN packet is simply not accepted:

```
# tcpdump -i any port 1443
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
16:16:48.755212 IP crawl15.bl.semrush.com.58400 > localhost.1443: Flags [S], seq 3425146544, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 581481 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:16:49.357973 IP 62-210-215-100.poneytelecom.eu.34855 > localhost.1443: Flags [S], seq 2086014266, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 581632 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:16:49.773961 IP crawl15.bl.semrush.com.58400 > localhost.1443: Flags [S], seq 3425146544, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 581736 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

I've tried this after running `ufw disable`, just to make sure, and the problem also happens with disabled firewall.

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/lo/rp_filter 
0
```

What might be causing this?